# How can I stop spark-submit jobs on yarn in airflow with SSHOperator

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, airflow

I use airflow version 2.1.0 and here is my code:

```
task1 = SSHOperator(
ssh_hook=sshHook,
task_id='test_spark,
do_xcom_push=False,
command=command spark submit)
```

I submit on mode local and kill it -> work ok. But I run on mode yarn it when i kill it on UI airflow it doesn't work. can anyone help me? Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run it on yarn you need to execute the yarn command with the application id of the application.

The yarn command itself is :

> yarn application -kill enter_application_id

So you should try something like :

```
task1 = SSHOperator(
    ssh_hook=sshHook,
    task_id='test_spark,
    do_xcom_push=False,
    command=yarn application -kill enter_application_id)
```

For more information, yarn is a ressource negociator and airlfow is an orchestration tool. When you click on UI you kill the task on the orchestration tool (airflow), but yarn that instanciated the node for your job to run isn't aware of that. Therefor you need to notice yarn that you want to kill the job.

Comment: thanks for your answer. i add some config to my task in airflow and it works. my config is get_pty=True.

Comment: If my answer helped you, do you mind upvoting it ?

Comment: @RobertReynolds but is its spark streaming application , then how will the DAG/Airflow know the applicationID of yarn ? how do i get that and run this kill task every 10 days ?